# Passing data between two functions. 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, function, desktop-application

I am trying to make desktop-app for my science work.

I have a function that processes the data, and return me 3 list objects.  [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4f5U.png)

```
  def process(self):
    file_location = "'/Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science\ comput/Application/Sheet.xlsx'"
    sample = pd.read_excel('Sheet.xlsx', sheetname ='Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])

    list_of_index = []
    for i in range(len(sample.columns)):
        sample2 = sample.iloc[:, lambda sample: [i]]
        sample2 = sample2.columns[0]
        list_of_index.append(sample2)
    list_of_index   

    ...        ...        ...        ...        ...
    ...        ...        ...        ...        ...

    ...        ...        ...        ...        ...
    return fulllist, fulllist_percent, fulllist_click



def saveSample(self, process):
    fulllist, fulllist_percent, fulllist_click = process(self)
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('lul.xlsx')
    worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()


    row = 0

    for col, data in enumerate(fulllist):
        worksheet1.write_column(row, col, data)
    for col, data in enumerate(fulllist_percent):
        worksheet2.write_column(row, col, data)   
    for col, data in enumerate(fulllist_click):
        worksheet3.write_column(row, col, data)      


    workbook.close()
```

But when I try to get this lists, i get a "'bool' object is not callable" error. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx17N.png)

I'm pretty new to python, so I might make some stupid mistake, that i do not see

Comment: Post all code and errors here directly as text. Why would you post an image of text? Also, include it as an [mcve] so your problem is clear.

Comment: please post the code in your question. Link is not a good idea.

Comment: You also need to show how you are calling that method.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Comment: @daniel to call this method I use a button click

Comment: But what code do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, when asking a question you need to give all the relevant information. Rather than saying you use a button click to call this function, you need to show the actual code that assigns the button to the function.

In this case it is clear what the problem is. You are confused between two things called "process": one is a parameter to the function, which is presumably a boolean value, and the other is a method on the class.

To call a method you always need to refer to it via the instance, which inside another method is available via `self`. Note, however, you do not pass `self` as a paramater.

```
fulllist, fulllist_percent, fulllist_click = self.process()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Next time I'm gonna be more accurate with question